# Using :hover for class and child elements?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to use a `:hover` effect to change a rule for all `<p>` elements inside a `div`, but I am having trouble accomplishing this without creating a new class.

Can I not do something like this:

```
<class>:hover <class> p {
    //something
}
```

Here is a fiddle to show better: http://jsfiddle.net/34q33/

I know I can just add a class to the `<p>` `element`, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/34q33/1/

But I was curious why I have to give the `element` a unique `class` to accomplish this; or if I am going about it the wrong way.

Thanks and I apologize for the terrible title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a class for each element :

```
.item > p {
margin:0;
background: green;
opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover > p {
opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34q33/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `<p>` or some other child of .item to change styles you can use

`.item:hover :nth-child(2)`

also first first child you can use `.item:hover :nth-child(1)` or directly first-child selector `.item:hover :first-child`

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/34q33/4/)